# Get access token without user intervention C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I am running a workflow service which automatically posts messages from some blogs on a facebook page. But now facebook deprecate the offline_access permission and I need to find a solution if my application does not run for example 60 days and the access token expired.

I need to find a way to get a new access token with given username and password without user intervention...

Maybe someone of you have a good idea

Comment: Have your application do something innocuous from time to time so that the access token doesn't expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service make timed requests to the Facebook API, you won't need to worry about the token expiration. So, if you request some status or a specific FQL on a timed interval, your token will be extended and will let you post anytime you want.

This solution is a workaround. Even you try to do that, you won't cover all the scenarios. The better way is to mantain the user connected to your app, verifying some constant content day-by-day. With this behavior, you will have an access token for every entrance of the user.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that my the access token gets renewed when I do something with the API with this access token. But I need to find a way to get a new access token, if one expires (password change or expired). I thought maybe there is a way to gain a new access token if I have the login credentials.

Comment: Sure, I thought about this way too, but I didn't said because is not allowed by the [Facebook Privacy Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), as described in item 1.2.

Comment: I'm almost sure that's not correct - the token doesn't extend because you use it, you have to extend it yourself the next time the user is actively using the app - you can't extend them indefinitely without the user coming back to your app

Comment: Yes, it is correct and it is being confused nowadays, with the new access token validation. The token can be extended if your application is using the server-side authentication or if is a mobile (iOS/Android) application. [See the extend method](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: And, like I said before, even extending the access token with server-side auth, this solution will not cover all the scenarios.